# In Edit-Form I must enter a tab to make fields return with values, But they return "None" when I didn't enter their tabs in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a problem with my forms (I fixed it) by an idea I’ll mention here, But I think I miss something or Django Forms have a another good solution for it.
I have one page with(many tabs and as a result many forms and many inputs also).
All forms must save by one save button under one form `<form class="add-product-form"></form>` And
`<form class="edit-product-form"></form>`
The next image illustrate what I mean.

[image]

- My Problem :

In `add-product-form` everything is OK(Saving process has been done perfectly till now) but in `edit-product-form` I noticed that (Any inputs present in a tab I don’t enter, every input in this tab return `"None"` and the update process of `edit-product-form` leads to make the original data that I have saved in `add-product-form` return to None or to default - As `clean_field(self)` method stated)
Here is some of code of my `forms.py` file

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    name = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                # "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": "Write the product English name here ...",
            }
        ),
    )
    name_ar = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                # "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": "Write the product Arabic name here ...",
            }
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ( 
            'name', 'name_ar',
            'branch', 'pos_station', 'store',
            'barcode', 'reference_code',            
            'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4', 'name_5', 'name_6', 'name_7',
            'name_ar_1', 'name_ar_2', 'name_ar_3', 'name_ar_4', 'name_ar_5', 'name_ar_6', 'name_ar_7',
            'description', 'description_ar', 'short_description', 'short_description_ar',
          
        )

    def clean(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        print(
            'PRODUCT-FORM-CLEANED-DATA::::', super().clean(), 
        )
        return super().clean()
    
    def clean_name(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        FIELD = data.get('name')
        if FIELD == '':
            raise ValidationError('Please Fill Product English name') #"Product English name must be filled "
            # self.add_error("name", "Product English name must be filled ")
        
        print('ENGLISH-NAME::::', FIELD)
        return FIELD
    
    def clean_name_ar(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        FIELD = data.get('name_ar')
        if FIELD == '':
            self.add_error("name_ar", "Please Fill Product Arabic name")
        print('ENGLISH-NAME::::', FIELD)
        return FIELD
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        branches = Branches.objects.select_related('user').only()
        
        # self.fields['pos_station'].widget.attrs['value'] =  PosStation.objects.first()
        self.fields['pos_station'].empty_label = '--Select Pos Station--'  
        
        self.fields['store'].empty_label = "--Select Store--"        
        self.fields['branch'].empty_label = "--Select Branch--"        
        self.fields['branch'].queryset = branches        
        
        self.fields['reference_code'].widget.attrs['value'] = uuid.uuid1()



class ProductSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    times = [
            obj for obj in choices.TIMES
        ]
    dict_val = [
            (key, value) for key,value in dict(times).items()
        ]
    
    hint_ref = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Select(
            choices=dict_val,
        )
    )
    expire_period = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'value': Decimal(0.00)
            }    
        ),
        
    )
    expire_period_hint = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'value': Decimal('0.00')
            }
        )
    )
    order_limit_plus = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'value': Decimal('0.00')
            }
        )
    )
    order_limit_minus = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'value': Decimal('0.00')
            }
        )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = ProductSettings
        fields = [
            'sale', 'is_inventory', 'on_pos', 
            'sold', 'purchased', 'favorite', 
            'manufactured', 'consumable', 
            'inactive', 'is_deleted', 
            'has_limit_plus', 'has_limit_minus', 
            'order_limit_plus', 'order_unit_plus', 
            'order_limit_minus', 'order_unit_minus', 
            'expiry', 'expire_period', 'expire_ref', 
            'expire_period_hint', 'hint_ref',
        ]

    def clean_expire_ref(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        times = [
            obj for obj in choices.TIMES
        ]
        dict_val = [
            (key, value) for key,value in dict(times).items()
        ]
        if data['expire_ref'] == 'undefined':
            data['expire_ref'] = dict_val[0][0] #choices.TIMES[0][0]
        print('EXPIRE_REF::::', data['expire_ref'], 'DICT_VAL-FORMS.PY', dict_val[0][0] )
        return data['expire_ref']
    
    def clean_hint_ref(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        times = [
            obj for obj in choices.TIMES
        ]
        dict_val = [
            (key, value) for key,value in dict(times).items()
        ]
        if data['hint_ref'] == 'undefined':
            data['hint_ref'] = dict_val[0][0] #choices.TIMES[0][0]
        print('hint_ref::::', data['hint_ref'], 'DICT_VAL-FORMS.PY', dict_val[0][0])
        return data['hint_ref']
    
    def clean_expire_period(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        FIELD = data.get('expire_period')
        if FIELD == 'undefined':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        if FIELD == '':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        print('EXPIRE_PERIOD::::', FIELD)
        return FIELD
    
    def clean_expire_period_hint(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        FIELD = data.get('expire_period_hint')
        if FIELD == 'undefined':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        if FIELD == '':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        return FIELD
    
    def clean_order_limit_plus(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        FIELD = data.get('order_limit_plus')
        if FIELD == 'undefined':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        if FIELD == '':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        return FIELD
    
    def clean_order_limit_minus(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        FIELD = data.get('order_limit_minus')
        if FIELD == 'undefined':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        if FIELD == '':
            FIELD = Decimal('0.00')
        return FIELD

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

- My Idea That Fix The Problem Till Now

The idea that came to my mind to fix this issue is making (hidden inputs take “0” value and when user hit or enter the tab like pricing Tab the priceTab variable changed to “1” ).
Then after I’ve saved the form or have got any inputs values from this tab,
I’ve made a simple check if the variable of this tab is 0 or 1 (if it is 0 I skip saving process -fields of that tab didn’t changed -, if it is 1 then saving process will take place).
I know that Django forms has (form.has_changed() and form.changed_data())
But It always return with (True) even if no data changed (I activate them in another Forms that have low number of inputs and tabs) because debugging here (is very hurt and take many times) also to keep everything works as expected (I will return again to fit Django Form rules) but after I’ve finished primary step of my project.

This is part of my views.py

````
def edit_product(request, product_id)```
   pro_qs = Product.objects.select_related(
        'user').get(id=product_id)   

   form = ProductForm(
        request.POST or None, 
        instance=pro_qs,
        initial=pro_initial_data, #* for checking the form changed or not    
        prefix="pro",
    )
    settings_form = ProductSettingsForm(
        request.POST or None, 
        instance=settings_obj,
        prefix="set"
    )
    cat_form = ProductCategoryForm(
        request.POST or None,
        instance=pro_cat_obj, 
        prefix="cat"
    )
    # price_initial_data = {
    #     'purchasing_price': request.POST.get('price-purchasing_price'),
    # }
    # initial=price_initial_data,
    price_form = ProductPriceForm(
        request.POST or None, 
        instance=pro_price_obj,
        prefix="price", 
    )
    
    extension_form = ProductExtensionForm(
        request.POST or None, prefix="extension")
    
    #* unit conversions
    conv_form = UnitConversionsForm(request.POST or None)
    
    #* for adding new units to the product
    uom_form = UOMForm(
        request.POST or None,
        prefix="uom"
    ) 
    
    uom = UOM.objects.select_related(
        'product').filter(
            product_id=product_id
            ).order_by('id')
    uom_obj = [
        UOM.objects.select_related('product').get(id=obj.id) for obj in uom
    ]
    #* for editing UOM form
    edit_uom_form = [
        UOMForm(
            request.POST or None,
            instance=obj,
            initial={
                'unit':obj.unit,
            }
        ) for obj in uom_obj
    ]


   if request.accepts('*/*') and request.method == 'POST':
       ...
       if not form.is_valid():
            data['pro_id'] = None 
            msg = [
                (key + ': ' + value[0]['message']) for key, value in (
                    form.errors.get_json_data().items()
                )
            ]
            data['error'] = msg
            data['type'] = 'info'
            
            return JsonResponse(data)
        
        if not settings_form.is_valid():
            data['pro_id'] = None 
            msg = [
                (key + ': ' + value[0]['message']) for key, value in (
                    settings_form.errors.get_json_data().items()
                )
            ]
            data['error'] = msg
            data['type'] = 'info'
            
            return JsonResponse(data)

       ...
       if form.is_valid():
            save_form = form.save()
            save_form.updated_user = request.user
            print(
                'CHENGED-DATA:: ', form.changed_data,
                'form.has_changed()', form.has_changed()
            )
            # if form.has_changed():
            save_form.save()
            
        if request.POST.get('hide-settings') == '1': #? it comes as string from post
            if settings_form.is_valid():
                print('Product settings Form is valid') 
                save_settings_form = settings_form.save()
                
                save_settings_form.save()
            print('***SETTINGS FORM SAVED DONE*** ')
            
        elif request.POST.get('hide-settings') == '0':
            print('SETTINGS FORM DOES NOT CHANGED !!!')

        if request.POST.get('hide-category') == '1': #? it comes as string from post
            if cat_form.is_valid():
                print('Product Category Form is valid') 
                save_cat_form = cat_form.save()
                
                save_cat_form.save()
            print('***@@@CATEGORY FORM SAVED DONE... ')
            
        else:
            print('CATEGORY FORM DOES NOT CHANGED !!!')
       

       #? message for declaring that product saved successfully
        msg = "Product form Updated successfully..."
        data['error'] = msg
        data['type'] = 'success'
        
        return JsonResponse(data)


   context = {
        "form": form,
        "cat_form": cat_form,
        "set_form": settings_form,
        "price_form": price_form,
        "extension_form": extension_form,
        "img_form": img_form,
        "image_product": image_product,
        "image_product_obj": image_product_obj,
        
        "edit_uom_form": edit_uom_form,
        "uom_form": uom_form,
        "uom": uom,
        'uom_obj': uom_obj,
        'uom_ids': uom_ids,
        'unit_purchase': unit_purchase,
        'unit_purchase_ids': unit_purchase_IDS,
        
        'unit_sale': unit_sale,
        'unit_sale_ids': unit_sale_IDS,
        "qs": pro_qs,
        "pro_unit": model_func_unit,
        "unit_price": model_func_price,
        'unit_id': get_unit_id,
        "product_id": product_id,
        'last_unit': uom.last().unit.name,
        'title': 'Edit Product',
    }
    return render(request, "products/edit_product.html", context)
````

- My questions are:

1- What have I missed here ?

2- Why I have to enter a tab to get inputs values from this tab
by (request.POST.get("field_name")) ?

3- Is there a good solution for this issue ?

4- Is my idea true to overcome this issue (it succeeded to fix
the issue till now)?

Any suggestions or ideas

Comment: Kindly I need some help here, Could you please discuss with me if I missed something? .
If my question needs clarifications, Please let me know